# Как сделать спойлер с анимацией?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".more").click(function(){

        $("#id2").animate(
         {
         height: "90"        
         }, 120)
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Два вопроса.

1) Как сделать, чтобы вместо "id2" ( $("#id2").animate) вставлялся id на который щелкаешь?

2) Как сделать, чтобы высота не была фиксирована? Т.е. ставить height:auto и анимация разворачивала спойлер до нужной "высоты"?

Comment: как-то странно код вставился...

Comment: Добавьте еще и html код, которым управляет функция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $(this).animate(...);
2) Пример:

```
$('.more').each(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    t.data('defHeight', t.height());
}).css('height', '40px');
```

И потом разворачивать по высоте до $(this).data('defHeight');

Answer (score 1):

1. Если кликаете по нужным id и они имеют класс more(т.е. обработчик висит на общем классе но с разными id), то просто вместо $("#id2").animate(); делайте $(this).animate();
2. Вопрос не совсем ясен, если честно...